# Using malloc() function to set global array size get a dump core

Tags: c

I have a global array variable called `int *PRIME_ARRAY`. Then in my `main` function I ask the user the length of this array, save it in `int quantita` and set it with `PRIME_ARRAY = malloc(sizeof(int) * quantita)`.

When I compile no errors, but when I execute it and insert a number, for example "7", it produce a core dump error. I try to debug it the "newbie way" putting `printf()` phrases among all the code. This way seems that the problem is using the `malloc()` function.

(I must have the array as global variable. `next_prime()` must have just `int last` as argument)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int next_prime(int last);

int *PRIME_ARRAY;

int main(void)
{
  int quantita;

  printf("Quanti numeri primi vuoi stampare ? ");
  scanf("%i", &quantita);

  PRIME_ARRAY = malloc(sizeof(int) * quantita);

  int last = 2;

  for (int i = 0; i < quantita; i++){
    PRIME_ARRAY[i] = last;
    last = next_prime(last);
  }

  free(PRIME_ARRAY);
  return 0;
}

int next_prime(int last)
{
  printf("%i ", last);

  bool isPrime = false;

  do {
    last++;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(PRIME_ARRAY)/sizeof(int); i++){    
      if (last % PRIME_ARRAY[i] != 0) isPrime = true; break;    
    }    
  } while (!isPrime);

  return last;    
}
```

Comment: Apparently, there's nothing wrong with this part of your code, besides `null` being `NULL`. What do you do afterwards?

Comment: I don't really see a question in there. Also, that can't be your actual  code since that won't compile. Can we see the actual code that we can compile to replicate the problem? (Is your question, "What is a core dump and how do you debug them?" If so, it would help to know what debugger you want to use or what debugging techniques you prefer. There's definitely no "one right way" to debug.)

Comment: @ALL sorry, due to my bad internet connection I published half question.

Comment: I don't see a reason for a core dump yet, but `sizeof (PRIME_ARRAY)` is going to return the size of a pointer, not the size malloced. You want to pass the number of elements into `next_prime`.  Except, you want to pass the number of elements *in* the array, not the *size* of the array.  Otherwise, it's unnecessarily searching extra, uninitialized space in the array, which is filled with whatever garbage malloc gave you (no guarantee of initialization), so you will get unexpected behavior.

Comment: `sizeof(PRIME_ARRAY)/sizeof(int)` isn't what you expect. `PRIME_ARRAY` is still a pointer, so it's probably 8 bytes. When you dynamically allocate memory, you should pass a variable to know how big that memory area is. `sizeof(array)` only works if you declare it as an array in C.

Comment: Also, in the line `if (last % PRIME_ARRAY[i] != 0) break; isPrime = true;`, the assignment `isPrime = true;` is always performed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the memory management problems, there are ohter issues in OP's code (even in the one posted as answer):

```
int next_prime(int last)
{
    printf("%i ", last);
    bool isPrime = false;
    do {
        last++;
        for (int i = 0; i < array_lenght; i++) {
            if (last % PRIME_ARRAY[i] != 0) isPrime = true; break;
            //                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^          
        }
    } while (!isPrime);
    return last;
}
```

Due to do the lack of brackets, needed to define the scope of the `if` clause, the nested for-loop isn't actually a loop and the whole function acts as if it was written as:

```
int next_prime(int last)
{
    printf("%d ", last);
    do {
        last++;  
    } while (last % PRIME_ARRAY[0] == 0);
    return last;
}
```

As a matter of fact, they both generate the wrong output: all the odds, not only the primes. E.g. the first 20 numbers found are:

```
2 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31 33 35 37 39
```

Another issue is that the range of that loop should be limited to the already known primes, not to the entire array, which is uninitialized.

An easy fix, without adding any other global variable (there are too many of those already) could be the following snippet.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int next_prime(int last);

int *PRIME_ARRAY, array_length;

int main(void)
{
    printf("How many prime numbers do you want to print? ");

    if (scanf("%d", &array_length) != 1  ||  array_length < 1)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    // Allocate and initialize to zero the array of primes
    PRIME_ARRAY = calloc(array_length + 1, sizeof *PRIME_ARRAY);
    if (!PRIME_ARRAY)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    int last = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array_length; i++)
    {
        // First find the next prime, then print it. Move all the
        // update logic to the called function
        last = next_prime(last);
        printf("%d ", last);
    }
    putchar('\n');

    free(PRIME_ARRAY);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int next_prime(int last)
{
    bool has_factors;
    int i;
    do {
        ++last;
        has_factors = false;
        // Check only the known primes
        for (i = 0; PRIME_ARRAY[i] != 0; i++)
        {
            if (last % PRIME_ARRAY[i] == 0)
            {
                has_factors = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    } while ( has_factors  ||  last <= 1 );
    // Update here the array of primes, if there's space left
    if ( i < array_length )
        PRIME_ARRAY[i] = last;

    return last;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the `PRIME_ARRAY` as a local, not a global, variable. Then change the argument list of `next_prime` to include the base address of the array and its size. You use `sizeof` which gives the size of the base pointer, which is the word size on your machine. Instead you need to pass the `quantita` variable to the `next_prime` function.

Comment: I cannot do this. `next_prime` must have only one argument, `int last`

Comment: @Puzzolente Then you must keep the size of the array as a global too. Then use that size variable, not `sizeof`, to view the size of the array

Answer (score 0):

As Perette Barella and Yuri J said in the comments, the error is that `sizeof(PRIME_ARRAY)` in this case return the size of the pointer. `sizeof(array)` works fine only when the array is declared as an array, so with a static length. (Like `int array[7]` or `int array[] = {1, 2, 3}`)

To fix the code, I simply added a global variable call `int array_lenght`, substituded `scanf("%i", &quantita);` with `scanf("%i", &array_length);` and `i < sizeof(PRIME_ARRAY)/sizeof(int)` with `i < array_lenght`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int next_prime(int last);

int *PRIME_ARRAY, array_lenght;

int main(void){

  printf("Quanti numeri primi vuoi stampare ? ");

  scanf("%i", &array_lenght);

  PRIME_ARRAY = malloc(sizeof(int) * array_lenght);

  int last = 2;

  for (int i = 0; i < array_lenght; i++){

    PRIME_ARRAY[i] = last;

    last = next_prime(last);

  }

  free(PRIME_ARRAY);

  printf("\n");

  return 0;

}

int next_prime(int last){

  printf("%i ", last);

  bool isPrime = false;

  do {

    last++;

    for (int i = 0; i < array_lenght; i++){

      if (last % PRIME_ARRAY[i] != 0) isPrime = true; break;

    }

  } while (!isPrime);

  return last;

}
```